# Should Publish work with MassTransit's Mediator?

Tags: masstransit

The `Send` method works with Mediator, but not the `Publish` method. Nothing is received by consumers.
Is that on purpose? Is it expected in a later version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish should work, but I just realized that it throws a `NullReferenceException` if there isn't a pipe specified. That's a bug, I've found and fixed it. [Issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1812)